# OpenGL model renders fine for a while, then it renders sparsely after a random amount of time

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glm-math

I hacked together a sample OpenGL demo, and I have noticed an issue. I can load and render a model correctly. After a few seconds, however, the model stops being rendered correctly.

**EDIT: The change from normal to bad happens at after a random amount of seconds and occurs instantly. Once it goes bad, it never changes back.**

**All the EventLoop::Start() function does right now is block and call the callback in a loop until isRunning is false.**

Here is what the model looks like before it messes up:
[image: fine model]

Here is what it looks like after a few seconds:
[image: broken model]

Here is my code:

```
// nasty globals
static Camera* camera;
static ModelData dragonModel;
static ShaderProgram program;

using namespace std;

// called by an event loop class until isRunning is false
void callback(bool *isRunning)
{
        SDL_Event event;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            // update the camera position
            switch(event.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                *isRunning = false;
                SDL_Quit();
                break;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_UP:
                    camera->MoveBy(glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
                    break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    camera->MoveBy(glm::vec3(0, -1, 0));
                    break;
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    camera->MoveBy(glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
                    break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    camera->MoveBy(glm::vec3(-1, 0, 0));
                    break;
                case SDLK_w:
                    camera->MoveTo(glm::vec3(0, 0, -5));
                    break;
                case SDLK_s:
                    camera->MoveTo(glm::vec3(0, 0, 5));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;
            }

        }

    // calc matrices
    glm::mat4 scale = glm::scale(glm::mat4(), glm::vec3(1, 1, 1));
    glm::mat4 model = scale * glm::mat4(1.0);
    glm::mat4 MVP = DisplayManager::GetProjectionMatrix() * model;

    // send the final matrix over
    GLuint MVPLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program.id, "MVP");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));

    // clear and draw
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, dragonModel.num_indices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);

    DisplayManager::Swap(); // SDL_GL_SwapWindow()
}

#undef main
int main(void)
{
    // create a display and get the camera
    DisplayManager::Create("yay", 800, 600);
    camera = DisplayManager::GetCamera();
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    DisplayManager::Swap();

    // load the dragon model
    load_model(&dragonModel, "dragon.obj");

    // load the shader program
    program = ShaderManager::LoadProgram("basicShader.vert", "basicShader.frag");
    ShaderManager::SetCurrentProgram(program);

    if(!IsValidProgram(program))
    {
        printf("\ninvalid program detected\n");
    }

    // set up the model's VAO and leave it bound
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    GLuint dragonVAO = -1;
    GLuint VBO = -1;
    GLuint EBO = -1;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &dragonVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(dragonVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dragonModel.num_vertices * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), dragonModel.vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, dragonModel.num_indices * sizeof(GLuint), dragonModel.indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // free the model because we don't need our copy
    free_model(&dragonModel);

    // start the event loop
    EventLoop eventLoop;
    eventLoop.SetLoopCallback(&callback);
    eventLoop.Start();

    return 0;
}
```

And here are my shaders:

basicShader.vert

```
#version 330
uniform mat4 MVP;
layout(location = 0) in vec3 in_position;
out vec4 passed_color;
void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(in_position, 1.0f);
    passed_color = vec4(normalize(in_position), 1.0f);
}
```

basicShader.frag

```
#version 330

in vec4 passed_color;

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = passed_color;
}
```

**What I have Tried:**

- Updating Drivers
- Making sure that the number of indices isn't changing when
  it messes up.

I don't see any updating of model data or changing in draw calls that would make this happen. I am suspicious of glDrawElements, glClear, my matrix updates, and the creation of my context:

```
void DisplayManager::Create(const char *title, int width, int height)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    camera_ = new Camera();

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);


    window_ = SDL_CreateWindow(title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    glContext_ = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window_);

    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window_, glContext_);
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if(err != GLEW_OK)
    {
        printf("glew failed to init: %s", glewGetErrorString(err));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try clearing the colour and depth buffers every frame, if you aren't already.

Comment: I am. Its done by the "// clear and draw" comment.

Comment: Have you tried this on a computer other than the one you've been seeing the problem on?

Comment: Nope, if I can't fix it then I will, but it will be super tedious.

Comment: Tried to enhance the precision yet?

Comment: Considering I don't know what that means, no ;)

Comment: Does `start` do anything beside call `callback` in a loop? How does the corruption begin - is it sudden, slow, does it continue to get progressively worse?

Comment: @William Kappler I think that deserves an edit.

Comment: @rationalcoder : Afais you use the `float` types of glm; have you tried `double`? Btw - how large is your dragon mesh (order of number of vertices), and what is the extent to distance ratio?

Comment: @rationalcoder Thanks for the details. I'm thinking it's not impossible this is due to some hardware fault like overheating, which I have seen cause corruption exactly like this. Since you're running almost no CPU logic, the video card will be running to levels that you'd rarely see in a production program using GPU acceleration. That wouldn't usually be associated with a sudden change, though.

Comment: @decltype_auto I just ruled out the setting of the matrix as the problem, so I don't think it is glm. As for the ratio, considering that I can move the model around before the bug and have it render fine, i don't think it is a ratio issue.

Comment: @WilliamKappler He sets an attribute-array for that.

Comment: @WilliamKappler Yes I am, it gets its value from the 0th vertex attrib array, which, in my case, is filled with vertex data.

Comment: @rationalcoder I saw that after I posted, hence deleted comment.

Comment: @rationalcoder: that may be a misconception, because errors may accumulate. But I cannot help if you don't provide the parameters of your model I asked you for.. Bye!

Comment: @decltype_auto 300,000 vertices, and .1f / 100.0f ratio ? I'm not sure if those are the numbers you are talking about.

Comment: I didn't ask for the near and far plane, but the ratio of the extent of the model and the distance (of the cam, of course, what else?) to the model.

Comment: @decltype_auto I don't know what the "extent" is, but I have tried it with a cube with side length 1 at the origin and the cam from 2 to five units away from it (still having the issue). I am currently trying to set up a project on a different machine to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AMD GAMING EVOLVED!!!**

Once, while rendering a cube, the "Turning On" and "Save Highlight - Ctrl F2" appeared on the top left of my screen. Apparently this is a screen capturing thing from AMD Gaming Evolved. It just so happened that my rendering went wonky at the same time the message appeared.

I killed the process "Raptr Desktop" and my models now render correctly!

I have notified AMD and uninstalled the program.

This is pretty comical after staring at my code for days trying to find the bug :)